# how do I write this in Python?

Tags: python, c++

So there is this c++ code I am migrating to python and I am stuck at one point where I need to write a structure in python, I have handled that by using class. But the difficulty here is the structures has pointers as members and I don't know how to proceed with this

```
typedef struct {
  string_t                     filename;
  string_t                     version;
  node_list_t                 *node_list;
  valtable_list_t             *valtable_list;
  message_list_t              *message_list;
  envvar_list_t               *envvar_list;
  attribute_rel_list_t        *attribute_rel_list;
  attribute_definition_list_t *attribute_definition_list;
  signal_group_list_t         *signal_group_list;
  network_t                   *network;
} dbc_t;
```

In the above code all the data types are type definitions and I am stuck with the pointers on the RHS.
Can someone help me in handling this ?

Thanks! :)

Comment: They should already act like pointers.

Comment: Please post your Python code (well, a [mcve] actually - we don't want the full code, just a relevant example). AND by all means [read this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) to understand how Python variables differ from C / C++ ones. You will then understand that Python doesn't have pointers because it doesn't need them to do the same thing ;-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Edit: Retracting my statements as that caused confusion.

All you need to do is assign the variable directly to the member as variables act as reference in case of objects.

You can read more about how python is pass by value for all variables, but how that means its pass by reference for objects [here](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/).

Comment: Link leads to some Java question, can you please provide the correct link ?

Comment: Sorry regarding that, have updated the link.

Comment: "In python, objects are passed by reference" no they are not. Python **never uses pass by reference semantics**, which refers to an evaluation strategy (i.e. when and how function arguments are resolved). Python is **not pass by value** and it is **not pass by reference**. It is *neither of those*. It is call by object sharing (or in your link, call by object reference). This whole "it's call by value but all values are references" is a Java-ism, which confuses implementation details for the actual semantics and evaluation strategy. It isn't true.

Comment: If you want to link to an article explaining how arguments are passed in Python, use the right article please: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers after the edit, the article is actually quite good. But that is also a good article you reference.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga hum yes indeed - retracting my downvote ;-) (and yes, Ned Batchelder's article is really a great resource - it should be part of the official doc as far as I'm concerned).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I wish I could link it as a duplicate almost every day.

Comment: @EdwinClement you may still want to edit your post to avoid the terms "passed by reference" and "passed by value" - neither really describe how Python works and it can only induce confusion...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, we'd need a community post or something like this ;-)